# How can I override the render strategy for a specific page in wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have an application which needs to accept a POST request from an outside server, to confirm payment. I don't want to break the default wicket render strategy (REDIRECT_TO_BUFFER) which is serving to give the users a nicer experience than ONE_PASS_RENDER would, however, the external service is not happy with the 302, and keeps retrying until it gives up.

Is there some sensible way that I can tell wicket to use ONE_PASS_RENDER for only the specific page that handles this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Resource` instead of a `Page` to handle this request. That way, you can return whatever response you want (both HTTP headers and payload) to keep the external service happy.

It's a lower level API, though. If you need to respond with a rendered page, you may need to render it yourself (with lots of `println()` calls), or hack some way to Wicket to do it.

But since it is a response to a external service, I assume it will expect some kind of simple text, XML or JSON response, which are easy enough to do by hand.

Comment: Interesting, I might give that a try tonight.

We got an answer of the Wicket mailing list which is working, but it's anything but intuitive. Essentially we've created a landing page, which on construction throws a RestartResponseException constructed with a page provider with the actual page wanted and a RedirectPolicy#NEVER_REDIRECT.